# why does part of the content scale on this slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have used THIS tutorial to create a full-screen version for a website I am working on. 
As you may have noticed I have succeeded in making most of the changes I needed.

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/68/

But I am unable to figure out why the cans that shrink and grow every time the slides are clicked and made active.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/moburukolozu/1)

I have a feeling it has something to do with the Slides changing their width when going from active to smaller slides, But I do not understand why should the content grow/shrink with it.

```
                        //  resize currentslide to small version
                        currentSlide.stop().animate({
                            width: _width * 0.065
                        });
```

Is there anyone that can help me understand why this is happening?

All I want is for the click to reveal the slide and the cans to stay the size they are suppose to be. Just like the original tutorial a clean reveal to the content.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the cans expand is not a JavaScript issue, its because the CSS for the can is width:100% when its a small slider and when the new slide is clicked, the active slide goes from 60% to 10% and therefore the can takes up 100% of it.

```
.slide .can {
position: absolute;
width: 150%;
left: -56%;
bottom: 0;
right:auto;
}
```

The easiest solution would be to turn the values into pixels so that it stays the size it is while transitioning. But that perhaps complicates responsive behaviour.